# Excel; find if a case start/stop time occurs in an set interval

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of case times:

21:04 - 23:24
23:09 - 01:29
23:00 - 23:55
02:22 - 05:54

I need to count if the case was going during the period 2100-2359 and/or 0000-0600

I have tried nested IF's and If statements with ANDs & ORs but there is always something that escapes the logic, meaning it isnt counted when it should be counted.

I have also used
=IF(AND(G3>=MIN(21/24),H3<=MAX(23.99/24)),"YES","") (my times are in decimal percent of 24 hours)

which comes close, but also misses some items.

Any ideas?  Thanks!!
Pk

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

I think our solutions are basically the same. We use different representations for the times. 

Both solutions fail to find cases that start before the time interval and end after the interval   I’ll probably have to do several tests independently and then if any one of them trips the flag then look for that. I was hoping for a simpler solution with perhaps a  complex formula. 

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

One very crude possibility would be to have an auxiliary list of enumerated minutes of the day.

That is: 00:00 is 0, 00:01 is 1, ..., 21:00 is 1260, ... 23:59 is 1440.

To get the index number for each time of the day, you just need to multiply the number of hours by 60 and sum the number of minutes. For example, 21:04 is 21*60+4 = 1264.

Then, comparing 21:04 with 21:00-23:59 is the same as comparing 1264 with 1260 and 1440.

You basically want to count cases where the time index numbers fall between 0 and 360, or between 1260 and 1440.

For the actual Excel formula to check the cases, it would help to know the structure of your data.

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

I think our solutions are basically the same. We use different representations for the times. 

Both solutions fail to find cases that start before the time interval and end after the interval   I’ll probably have to do several tests independently and then if any one of them trips the flag then look for that. I was hoping for a simpler solution with perhaps a  complex formula. 

Thanks again